# Jetpack Compose shows scaled images pixelated

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-jetpack-compose

I'm migrating from XML layouts to Jetpack Compose and noticed that the Image composable does not scale an image as good as `ImageView` when the image gets cropped.

[image: Top image is from Jetpack Compose, bottom image is an ImageView]

The image on the top is added via Jetpack Compose, the one at the bottom is an `ImageView`.
For comparison, I added them next to each other like this:

```
Column {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_image),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier.size(280.dp)
    )
    Spacer(
        modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp)
    )
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            ImageView(context).apply {
                scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
                setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image)
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.size(280.dp)
    )
}
```

The effect is depending on the image which is used and I noticed it's mostly promiment on low-end devices, however I would expect Jetpack Compose to have the same or higher image quality, as it is the new framework for building UI on Android.

Is there something I'm missing which can give me the same quality as `ImageView`?

Comment: I don't see the difference

Comment: I see the difference on your images, but failed to reproduce it. To easy testing I've made this [sample code](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/d789e43da4594cb5dab99ff3584ba5d7). If you still can reproduce it with my sample, provide your image so I can test

Comment: Sorry, the initial images didn't show the effect very good, I edited my question. I also created an issue on issue-tracker and will post an answer if I get a reply.
@PhilipDukhov I noticed that it is easiest to reproduce on low-end devices and emulators

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am having a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312214/how-to-use-high-resolution4k-image-in-android-app

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vectorImage, you should use ImageVector.vectorResource instead painterResource

```
Icon(
        imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.vectorId),
        contentDescription = "bar action image",
        tint = if (!uiData.enabled) LightSteelBlue else uiData.iconTint,
        modifier = Modifier.size(iconScaleDefault)
    )
```

Cause, when you use a raster image, rescaling may be pixelize.
See also https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/images/compare