# How to use high resolution(4k) image in android app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-image, coil

I am getting high-resolution images from an API and displaying them on my app. I am not familiar with dealing with high-resolution images or images in general so I was surprised when I saw the images being blurry on my app.

1)What can be done to display in high resolution

2)What can be done mitigate the loss of resolution?

I am using the Coil library to load images into an Image composable on android.

Testing on a google pixel 3a.

Here is an example of the difference between the app displaying an image and the browser displaying another:[image]

[image]

My composable looks like this:

```
Image(
      painter = rememberImagePainter(
                    imageUrl,
                    builder = { allowHardware(false) }
                ),
      contentDescription = "",
      modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .aspectRatio(1f),
      contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
     )
```

Update:

1. I have tried using an ImageView instead of a composable but I still
   get the same result.

Comment: Try loading the image (using Coil or Glide or whatever) into an `ImageView`, to help determine if it is Coil's Compose UI support is the source of your difficulty.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to make a difference... I appreciate the idea though

Answer (score 0):

Inside `builder`, force the image size in pixels to your preferred size.

```kt
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        imageUrl,
        builder = {
            allowHardware(false)
            size(image.width, image.height)
        }
    ),
    contentDescription = "",
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(1f),
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
)
```

Be careful though when specifying really high resolution, it will cause crash `RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large bitmap`

Comment: it didn't do much other than scale the image, the quality remained the same